# FindFormula: can I change the standard TargetFunctions?

Tags: functions, fitting

FindFormula seems to have a limited number of TargetFunctions:

> Possible functions for TargetFunctions are Plus, Times, Power, Sin,
>   Cos, Tan, Cot, Log, Sqrt, Csc, Sec, Abs, and Exp.

Is it possible to define my own set of those functions (either built-in or owner-defined) so that I can look for a fit that returns combinations of them (as opposed to a standard nonlinear fitting, where one can only find free parameters) ?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Likely an average user can't do that. I tried a modified example from the documentation to FindFormula  fit2 = FindFormula[data, x, 
  TargetFunctions -> {Times, Log, Plus, Tanh}] and obtained an error communication and returned input.

Comment: Any chances that it will be possible to do so in the foreseeable future?